# qstackedwidget cannot link to qcombobox

Tags: qt, qstackedwidget

I'm trying to use combo box to control multiple page. I have created some custom widget via coding and also some `QFrame` in widget form too. But I can't seem to find any solution to go around this. I have try to use `Qstackwidget` but the program hand in the process.

```
stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget;
parentLayout1 = new QWidget;
parentLayout2 = new QWidget;
layout1 = new QGridLayout(parentLayout1);
layout2 = new QGridLayout(parentLayout2);

//Default layout to be linearity
layout1->addWidget(ui->TimeL, 0,1);
layout1->addWidget(ui->FreqL, 0,7);
layout1->addWidget(time1, 1,1,3,4);
layout1->addWidget(ui->PlusL, 4,3);
layout1->addWidget(time2, 5,1,3,4);
layout1->addWidget(ui->EqualL, 8,3);
layout1->addWidget(time3, 9,1,3,4);
layout1->addWidget(freq1, 1,7,3,4);
layout1->addWidget(ui->PlusL2, 4,9);
layout1->addWidget(freq2, 5,7,3,4);
layout1->addWidget(ui->EqualL2, 8,9);
layout1->addWidget(freq3, 9,7,3,4);
layout1->addWidget(ui->ProFrame,0,15,3,2);
layout1->addWidget(ui->InfoFrame,10,15,2,2);
layout1->addWidget(ui->LinearFrame,3,15,7,2);
stackedWidget->widget(1)->show();
```

Can you help me out with this problem? Note that I have multiple Qframe in my form. But I can't seem to hide them when i only want to display 1 qframe.

Answer (score 1):

You have `parentLayout1` and `parentLayout2` but you never added them to the stacked widget and trying to access the second widget (`stackedWidget->widget(1)`). Add this before that line.

```
stackedWidget->addWidget(parentLayout1);
stackedWidget->addWidget(parentLayout2);
```

Also, you haven't added anything to the second layout `layout2`.

Comment: Hi I'm able to make it to work but is it possible to share the same widget in all my layout

Comment: can you elaborate?.. could you please accept this as answer if it solved the initial problem?